# How to groupby pandas dataframe and sum values in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with 3 columns (CHAR, VALUE, and WEIGHT).

- CHAR column contains duplicate values which I need to group ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C'].
- VALUE column has a unique value for every unique CHAR [10, 10, 10, 15, 15, 20].
- WEIGHT column has various values [1, 2, 1, 4, 4, 6].

Consider an example of my initial dataframe:

[image]

I need to create a new dataframe which will have 3 columns.

- CHAR which will not have any duplicates
- T_VALUE (total value) which will have a sum of this CHAR's value and all its weights
- T_WEIGHT (total weight) which will have a sum of this CHAR's weights

Result would look like this:

[image]

I would highly appreciate any help.

Comment: `df.goupby('char').agg('sum')` ... I think ... without actually trying it

Comment: It is almost what I was looking for. With a bit of research, I was able to solve my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `+=` instead:

```
newDF = df.groupby(['CHAR', 'VALUE'], as_index=False)['WEIGHT'].sum()
newDF['VALUE'] += newDF['WEIGHT']
```

Answer (score 1):

I was actually able to answer my own question.
Here is the solution:

```
d = {'CHAR': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C'],
     'VALUE': [10, 10, 10, 15, 15, 20], 
     'WEIGHT':  [1, 2, 1, 4, 4, 6]}
df = pandas.DataFrame(data=d)

newDF = df.groupby(['CHAR', 'VALUE'], as_index=False)['WEIGHT'].sum()
newDF['VALUE'] = newDF['VALUE'] + newDF['WEIGHT']
```